# Determine the effect of each variable and interaction in regression analysis

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, p-value

I am studying the effect of two variables `x1` and `x2` on response variable `y`. Interaction term is included in the analysis. So our equation is

```
g(y) = aX1+bX2+cX1X2
```

My question is:

1. Determine if there is any interaction between the two variables.

   I can run the regression and look at the p value of coefficient of interaction term `c`. OR I can run two nested models with and without interaction term, then do likelihood ratio test. Which method should I adopt? What's is the difference between these two ways?
2. How to look at the effect of each variables on y if interaction term is significant?

My understanding is if there is interaction, the effect of X1 on y is dependent on X2. So we cannot determine the effect of X1 on y by itself. We need to look at the effect of X1 at each level of X2, if X2 is factor. Is that correct? What if both of them are continous?

3. how to determine the effect of each variable on y if interaction is not significant?

Should I just look at the p value of the coefficients a and b? OR should I refit the model without the interaction term, then look at the p value of their coefficient? OR can I fit two nested models: `g(y)=aX1+bX2+cX1X2`  and `g(y)=bX2+cX1X2`, then do likelihood ratio test?

Really appreciate it if any expert can help me understand it more clearly. Thanks a lot.